# Losing page id's on li's for menu when there's multiple menus

Tags: php, wordpress

I created a menu which I output on a page... each `li` of the menu had the page ID as an `id` allowing me to target specific `li`'s.

When I added the 2nd and 3rd location for the same menu, all the id's disappeared so a lot of my styling messed up due to it no longer outputting the id's. **How can I get these back when there's multiple menus?**

I'm registering 3 menu locations using the following:

```
// Register our themes menu locations
function register_menus() {
    register_nav_menu('primary-menu', __('Primary Menu'));
    register_nav_menu('mobile', __('Mobile Menu'));
    register_nav_menu('products', __('Products Menu'));        
    register_nav_menu('footer-menu', __('Footer Menu'));
}
add_action('init', 'register_menus');
```

Assigning the same menu to the 3 locations:

[image]

Then outputting in my template with the following:

```
<?php if ( has_nav_menu( 'primary-menu' ) ) {
wp_nav_menu( array(
  'container'=>'div',
  'menu_class'=>'1',
  'theme_location' => 'primary-menu',
  'walker' => new CSS_Menu_Maker_Walker(),
  'items_wrap' => '<ul class="primary-menu-1">%3$s</li></ul>'
));
} ?>


<?php if ( has_nav_menu( 'mobile' ) ) {
  wp_nav_menu( array(
    'container'=>'div',
    'menu_class'=>'2',
    'theme_location' => 'mobile',
    'walker' => new CSS_Menu_Maker_Walker(),
    'items_wrap' => '<ul class="primary-menu-2">%3$s</li></ul>'
  ));
} ?>


<?php if ( has_nav_menu( 'products' ) ) {
  wp_nav_menu( array(
    'container'=>'div',
    'menu_class'=>'3',
    'theme_location' => 'products',
    'walker' => new CSS_Menu_Maker_Walker(),
    'items_wrap' => '<ul class="primary-menu-3">%3$s</li></ul>'
  ));
} ?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding `'menu'=>'my-class-name',` to each menu instance brings them back.

Answer (score 0):

Add for all the instance you have add
 'menu'=>'name', 
Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

please add the Parameters 
menu, menu_class, menu_id.

and use this link for the further https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/